Azure Repo Setup for Nexus Repo
We have our own company framework for testing and all jar are stored in nexus repo.
Whenever running my automation framework,all required jars are getting downloaded from nexus repo via pom dependancy.
I want to setup a azure repo and all nexus repo required jar to be downloaded in azure repo.
If it is done,i will do run my automation via azure repo with CI/CD.
Any azure expert help for this....

In Azure DevOps, you should upload your packages (.jar) to Azure Artifact and put your projects into Azure Repo.
According to Azure Artifacts ,

Azure Artifacts enables developers to efficiently manage all their dependencies from one place. With Azure Artifacts, developers can publish packages to their feeds and share them within their team, across organizations, and even publicly across the internet. Azure Artifacts also allows developers to consume packages from different feeds and public registries such as NuGet.org or npmjs.com. Azure Artifacts supports the following package types: NuGet, npm, Python, Maven, Cargo, and Universal Packages.

According to Azure Repos,

Azure Repos is a set of version control tools that you can use to manage your code.

Go to your Project -> Create an artifact -> Connect to feed -> Select your package management tool and follow the instructions to connect to the feed and then publish and download packages.

You can see your packages in the feed as shown below:

Official docs for your reference:

Connect your Maven project to an Azure Artifacts feed. Select your own package type.
Publish your first package.


I have tried...But got 401 error

Ensure that you have followed the instructions to connect to the feed: 1. Add the repo to both your pom.xml's <repositories> and <distributionManagement> sections. 2. Add or edit the settings.xml file in your local ${user.home}/.m2. Generate a Personal Access Token with Packaging read & write scopes and paste it into the <password> tag. 3. Do not use the copy button in the Project setup, it will not copy the entire content. Copy all the content manually.
